# Finding roots of a polynomial without explicit coefficients

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am looking for a numerical algorithm to find all $n$ roots of a degree $n$ polynomial $P(x)$ *without explicit knowledge of its coefficients*. I can, however, evaluate $P(x)$ for any $x$.

I am aware that I could just sample $n+1$ points of $P$ to find its coefficients, then look for the roots as usual (e.g. by diagonalizing the companion matrix). But without some background information about the polynomial's coefficients or roots, it is not clear to me what is the best way to choose the sampling points (if the roots happen to be spaced much farther apart than my sampling points, the polynomial will be very close to a linear function in the sampled region and so I'd expect the extracted coefficients to be sensitive to numerical errors). That's why I would rather not go via the coefficients. But if anybody has a good idea how to choose the sampling points adaptively based on evaluations of $P(x)$ to get the coefficients of $P$ in a robust way, I am all ears.

In case anyone is curious, the reason I am looking into this is to solve the following problem: Given $N\times N$ (positive symmetric) matrices $A$ and $B$, I need to find all $x$ such that $Ax+B$ is singular. This of course leads to diagonalization of $A^{-1}B$ if $A$ is invertible. The interesting case is if it is not. My approach would then be to find the zeros of $\det(Ax+B)$ which is a polynomial of degree a most $N$ in $x$. I do not know its coefficients explicitly but I can sample the determinant for different $x$ rather easily.

Comment: Have you read [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Finding_roots_of_polynomials) part of wikipedia?

Comment: @P.Siehr You caught me there - I was so convinced all the algorithms described there make some use of the polynomial's coefficients that I didn't look at them properly. It seems like the _Durand-Kerner method_ might be quite close to what I'm looking for (provided I can choose the initial root estimates in a way that makes it converge reliably). The _Aberth method_ requires evaluating the derivative $P'(x)$ which I can't do directly.

Answer (score 3):

I must caution you against converting your real problem into the question of finding all zeros of a polynomial.

LAPACK and SCALAPACK already contains routines for your specific problem, the generalized eigenvalue problem for symmetric positive definite matrices,
$$Av = \lambda B v,$$
where $\lambda$ is a scalar and $v$ is an nonzero vector.

Unless you have unstated special requirements these routines should serve you well and they can also provide error estimates.

The nonsymmetric generalized eigenvalue problem is covered by LAPACK, and parallel implementations exist outside of ScaLAPACK.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track. I suspected this kind of problem must be quite common and so it should have well-known numerical solutions but I had a hard time finding any reference. Quite silly of me not to realize it would be simply called "generalized eigenvalue problem". The conversion to root-finding is still a bit relevant to me because I am also interested in a similar problem - determining when $A x^2 + B x + C$ is singular.

Comment: @aekmr. You are very welcome. One can not know everything and the correct course of action is to ask. Your second problem is called the quadratic eigenvalue problem. This is a good paper: http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/466/01/covered/MIMS_ep2006_256.pdf
Among other things this paper explains how a quadratic eigenvalue problem can be converted to a generalized eigenvalue problem.

Comment: Thanks again. Looks like you saved me once more from reinventing the wheel :). This seems like a nice reference. Their motivation for studying the problem is even very similar to mine (no surprise there, I suppose). My system is an RLC network while theirs is mechanical but the math is the same.